# How to fetch the record between two dates which is string in C++

Tags: c++

I am comparing two dates values which is defined as string variable in format YYYYMMDD. My requirement is to fetch the records between two dates. For this I have to 1st compare both dates then fetch value. I stuck in comparsion part.Please suggest me the way to do this.

I have following dates

start_dat , newStartDat , newEndDat & end_dat all are of string type.

I want to fetch value between newStartDat & newEndDat.

Note in C++.

Answer (score 0):

For dates in that format, a simple string comparison will give the right results. Assuming that "string type" means `std::string` (or something similar that provides lexicographical comparison operators), that would be:

```
if (date >= newStartDat && date <= newEndDat) {
    // It's in the range
}
```